# How can I edit CSS on the fly with ASP.NET code?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

Want to edit things like DIV size, color, positioning (absolute), height/width etc.

Comment: Could you provide some more details please?

Comment: Clarification: do you want to edit an individual element's style, or do you want to change the CSS applied to the page in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just output the CSS like any other with `Response.Write` or the `<%= someValue %>` methods.

Here are some of the other methods:
http://cfouquet.blogspot.com/2006/06/making-dynamic-css-content-with-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do with the information given, but to add css on the fly you can use **jQuery** to add the class to an element with those certain specifications.. you can have jquery wait in the background for something to happen on the client and just add the class with that certain style

**Example:**

```
<style>
 p { margin: 8px; font-size:16px; }
.color { color:blue; }

</style>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button1").click(function(){ 
      $("p:last").addClass("color");
   });
</script>

<p>Hello</p>
 <p>and</p>
<p>Goodbye</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "on the fly" you mean while the user is interacting with the page then you're going to need to use some javascript. I suggest learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com) as it provides an easy and effective way interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, you may want to look into *Themes* if you want to change the appearance of your site based on user preferences (Learning about *Skins* can help as well but master themes first).  This is really the right approach in the ASP.NET model unless you are looking just to adapt some specific output to certain data conditions.